# Getting related entities ASP.NET WebApi OData v4 results in "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

I followed [this asp.net tutorial by Mike Wasson](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4), and managed to set up the related entities just fine, but when I applied this logic to my project the more complex entity relations (in that there are more of them; that's the only difference) wouldn't succeed in an OData call, I got a 404 with this payload:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:19215/Menus(c94f7f98-6987-e411-8119-984be10349a2)/MenuPermissions'.",
    "innererror": {
      "message": "No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.",
      "type": "",
      "stacktrace": ""
    }
  }
}
```

The tutorial doesn't mention having to set up EdmModel navigations and Mike Wasson makes a point of pointing out that "asp.net is official documentation :-)"; so, I have spent a while trying to get these related entities working, thinking I had set up the project incorrectly.

I thought it might have something to do with the version of ASP.NET OData libraries that NuGet was installing (the NuGet Console installs 6.9.x, whereas the NuGet Dialog installs 6.5.x).  I also wondered if it was because I set the project up as a completely empty project and then use OWIN, so I tried it with a pure ASP.NET templated solution.  I also tried a couple of other possible solutions: OData-route-attributes on my controller methods; and including my data layer and models all in the same library (I have them separated out to keep DRY); I even attempted to use [the WebApi route debugger by Rick Anderson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx) - I wouldn't attempt to use this again!

All to no avail.

There was a brief moment when they worked, but I don't know why; they ceased to work on the next build/run - I guess I changed something in between, but it was very minor and I was losing confidence at every step.

Then I decided that Mike Wasson must've just taken the path of least resistance in his tutorial and so I reverted to [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082927/adding-a-custom-query-backed-navigation-property-to-odataconventionmodelbuilder#23113443) and modified it for use with ODataConventionModelBuilder and reuse, as I will explain in my answer below.

If anyone knows of a simpler way of getting this to work, please let me know, otherwise I recommend just biting the bullet and writing those EdmModel-Navigations in my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mention in the question, I tried many solutions to get this to work, but none were consistent in actually solving the problem and I kept avoiding the solution laid out in [this SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082927/adding-a-custom-query-backed-navigation-property-to-odataconventionmodelbuilder#23113443) because the tutorial is specifically for v4 and I figured that answer must be for an older version (how unwise).

So that answer does solve the problem, but requires some work to fit directly into OData v4 and an ODataConventionModelBuilder; this is why I have posted this question and answer; to provide a solution, specifically for OData v4 and ODataConventionModelBuilder, in the hope that others won't lose the time I have looking into this.

First, set up your EdmModel:

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
    builder.EntitySet<Menu>("Menus");
    builder.EntitySet<MenuPermission>("MenuPermissions");
    var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
    AddNavigations(edmModel); //see below for this method
    return edmModel;
}
```

Second AddNavigations:

```
private static void AddNavigations(IEdmModel edmModel)
{
    AddMenuPermissionsNavigation(edmModel);
}

private static void AddMenuPermissionsNavigation(IEdmModel edmModel)
{
    var menus = (EdmEntitySet) edmModel.EntityContainer.FindEntitySet("Menus");
    var menuPermissions = (EdmEntitySet)edmModel.EntityContainer.FindEntitySet("MenuPermissions");
    var menuType = (EdmEntityType) edmModel.FindDeclaredType("iiid8.cms.data.models.Menu"); //"iiid8.cms.data.models" is the C# namespace
    var menuPermissionType = (EdmEntityType)edmModel.FindDeclaredType("iiid8.cms.data.models.MenuPermission"); //as above, "iiid8.cms.data.models" is the C# namespace
    AddOneToManyNavigation("MenuPermissions", menus, menuPermissions, menuType, menuPermissionType);
    AddManyToOneNavigation("Menu", menus, menuPermissions, menuType, menuPermissionType);
}

private static void AddOneToManyNavigation(string navTargetName, EdmEntitySet oneEntitySet, EdmEntitySet manyEntitySet,
    EdmEntityType oneEntityType, EdmEntityType manyEntityType)
{
    var navPropertyInfo = new EdmNavigationPropertyInfo
    {
        TargetMultiplicity = EdmMultiplicity.Many,
        Target = manyEntityType,
        ContainsTarget = false,
        OnDelete = EdmOnDeleteAction.None,
        Name = navTargetName
    };
    oneEntitySet.AddNavigationTarget(oneEntityType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(navPropertyInfo), manyEntitySet);
}

private static void AddManyToOneNavigation(string navTargetName, EdmEntitySet oneEntitySet, EdmEntitySet manyEntitySet,
    EdmEntityType oneEntityType, EdmEntityType manyEntityType) {
    var navPropertyInfo = new EdmNavigationPropertyInfo {
        TargetMultiplicity = EdmMultiplicity.One,
        Target = oneEntityType,
        ContainsTarget = false,
        OnDelete = EdmOnDeleteAction.None,
        Name = navTargetName
    };
    manyEntitySet.AddNavigationTarget(manyEntityType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(navPropertyInfo), oneEntitySet);
}
```

Finally, call GetEdmModel from WebApiConfig.Register

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetEdmModel());
```

Now call your OData service's one-to-many and many-to-one navigations from your client and all should be good with your world.  In my case the calls look like this:

One-to-many:

```
http://localhost:19215/Menus(c94f7f98-6987-e411-8119-984be10349a2)/MenuPermissions
```

Many-to-one:

```
http://localhost:19215/MenuPermissions(ba0da52a-6c87-e411-8119-984be10349a2)/Menu
```

This answer assumes you set up the rest of your project just like Mike Wasson suggests in the tutorial linked in the question (that link is to Part 3 - you will need to [follow Part 1](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint) first!).

Answer (score 3):

I am using ASP.NET 5, Web API 2.2, and Entity Framework.

Another developer and I have also spent hours trying to figure out why, after following that same tutorial to a T, we couldn't get a relational route like the following to return anything other than a 404:

```
/odata/Supplier(1)/Products
```

We also tried the route debugger referenced in the OP, and it failed to produce anything other than a blank screen.

Luckily, for our needs, one of our random experiments worked, and that was to use the ODataRoute attribute like such:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("Suppliers({key})/Products")]
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProductsForSupplier([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer a few days ago but didn't have time to comment; this is certainly a simpler solution to getting this to work, which was, in essence, my original question, but I don't think it is a scalable, reliable solution for larger projects because any route that uses the entity needs to be decorated with the attribute. This is still a great solution for smaller projects that want to get up and running without the overhead of the work outlined in the currently accepted answer. If there is a consensus that I should change the accepted answer to this one then I will happily make it so.

Comment: I'd consider this more of a workaround than the correct answer.  So, I think for now everything is fine the way it is!  Thanks, though.

Comment: Sorry guys, as a community we can't accept a solution that totally circumvents default functionality as the best solution. I agree that it's hard to find good up to date documentation on some of this but it's often because we have asked the wrong question. The OData default convention is that you name your method GetProducts - see Getting Related Entities: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/entity-relations-in-odata-v4

Comment: Which community? I offered a solution that works, unlike the tutorial, using an OData provided attribute.  Circumvention is not what comes to mind.  I wish I could live in that ideal world where everything "just works", but the reality is otherwise. I can just imagine the look on my managers face if I said "Sorry, I have tested, working code but I refuse to push it, because as a community..."

Comment: Also, if ODataRoute really is considered circumvention, then it should be removed from the library.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller talks about this solution being accepted by the community as the best; I don't understand his point.  This answer will probably help out others, but it isn't the accepted answer and it isn't the answer with the most votes (so, the community isn't saying it's the best) but it is useful for those that haven't followed the conventions (which, as he rightly points out aren't easy to learn). **His comment might mislead people to assume that the problem in the question comes down to not following convention.  To make this assumption would be wrong.** My upvote for this answer stands.

Comment: Thanks @I-p for the backup ;) There is a place for ODataRoute, but it is not here. This solution involves an attribute on every controller method, it is hardly simpler than using the framework the way it was designed. My issue is that when new members see this article they will go and put ODataRoute attributes through all their controllers, overriding the default conventions. The misconception is that this is the ONLY way to get simple OData routes to work, when the actual issue here is that your OData runtime has been misconfigured or badly designed if you run into these issues.

Comment: Oh right, the reason I am passionate about this is actually in reference to this quote "For anyone else considering OData, I would highly recommend exploring other options first." I consider myself an OData evangelist and am deeply offended when people attack OData like this without any reasonable supporting arguments. If any one needs any one-on-one support on OData, IM me or tag me in a post and I'll either help you directly or point you to adequate resources or documentation that can. :)