# How do I expose a table valued function as a property of an entity set within a Web Api 2 OData v4 service?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

Please I need help figuring out how to expose a table valued function as a property of an entity set in a Web Api 2 OData v4 service.

My simplified schema has three tables, Structures, Locations, and LocationLinks.  A structure contains a graph with nodes (Locatons) and edges (LocationLinks). I access with an Entity Framework 6 Database first model.

```
Simplified Schema

  Structure:
      ID

  Locations:
      ID
      ParentID -> Structure

  LocationLinks
      A -> Location
      B -> Location
```

The goal is to access a structures collection of LocationLinks the same way I access a structure's location. i.e. To request structure #180's graph:

```
http://.../OData/Structures(180)/LocationLinks
http://.../OData/Structures(180)/Locations
```

The Locations query works automatically but I can't figure out how to add the right route to enable the LocationLinks query.  Thinking it would make my task easier I have added a Table Valued Function to my SQL server.  The function is present in my EF model and returns a collection of LocationLink entities:

```
StructureLocationLinks(@StructureID) -> LocationLinks
```

Unfortunately no matter what I try I cannot seem to make the Structure(180)\LocationLinks URL functional. This is my latest attempt:

StructuresController.cs snippet:

```
        // GET: odata/Structures(5)/Locations
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<Location> GetLocations([FromODataUri] long key)
        {
            return db.Structures.Where(m => m.ID == key).SelectMany(m => m.Locations);
        }

        // GET: odata/Structures(5)/LocationLinks
        [EnableQuery]        
        //[System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataRoute("Structures({key})")]
        public IQueryable<LocationLink> GetLocationLinks([FromODataUri] long key)
        {
            return db.StructureLocationLinks(key);
        }
```

WebApi.cs snippet:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            json.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
            //json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;

            //var cors = new System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            //config.EnableCors(cors);

            // Web API routes 
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = GetModel();

            config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "odata",
                routePrefix: null,
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

    public static ODataConventionModelBuilder GetModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

            builder.Namespace = typeof(Structure).Namespace;

            AddLocationLinks(builder);
            AddStructures(builder);
            builder.EntitySet<Location>("Locations");

            return builder;
        }

        public static void AddStructures(ODataModelBuilder builder)
        {
            var structSetconfig = builder.EntitySet<Structure>("Structures");
            var structConfig = structSetconfig.EntityType;

            var functionConfig = structConfig.Collection.Function("StructureLocationLinks");
            functionConfig.Parameter<long>("StructureID");
            functionConfig.Returns<LocationLink>();
        }


        public static void AddLocationLinks(ODataModelBuilder builder)
        {
            var type = builder.EntityType<LocationLink>();
            type.HasKey(sl => sl.A);
            type.HasKey(sl => sl.B);
            builder.EntitySet<LocationLink>("LocationLinks");
        }
```

The error I recieve is:

> {
>     "error":{
>       "code":"","message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://.../OData/Structures(180)/LocationLinks'.","innererror":{
>         "message":"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template
>   '~/entityset/key/unresolved'.","type":"","stacktrace":""
>       }   } }

Based on some searching I attempted to add an ODataRoute attribute to the controller:

```
// GET: odata/Structures(5)/LocationLinks
[EnableQuery]        
[System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataRoute("Structures({key})/LocationLinks")]
public IQueryable<LocationLink> GetLocationLinks([FromODataUri] long key)
{
    return db.StructureLocationLinks(key);
}
```

Which results in this error:

> The path template 'Structures({key})/LocationLinks' on the action
>   'GetLocationLinks' in controller 'Structures' is not a valid OData
>   path template. Found an unresolved path segment 'LocationLinks' in the
>   OData path template 'Structures({key})/LocationLinks'.

How can I make expose the LocationLinks from the Structures collection?  Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

I managed to get this working after finding this question:
[Adding a custom query backed Navigation Property to ODataConventionModelBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23082927/adding-a-custom-query-backed-navigation-property-to-odataconventionmodelbuilder)

I had to call .GetEdmModel on my ODataConventionBuilder object, then add the navigation property to the model with this function:

```
private static Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel AddStructureLocationLinks(IEdmModel edmModel)
        { 

            var structures = edmModel.EntityContainer.FindEntitySet("Structures") as EdmEntitySet;
            var locationLinks = edmModel.EntityContainer.FindEntitySet("LocationLinks") as EdmEntitySet;
            var structType = structures.EntityType() as EdmEntityType;
            var locLinksType = locationLinks.EntityType() as EdmEntityType;

            var structLocLinksProperty = new EdmNavigationPropertyInfo();
            structLocLinksProperty.TargetMultiplicity = Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmMultiplicity.Many;
            structLocLinksProperty.Target = locLinksType;
            structLocLinksProperty.ContainsTarget = true; 
            structLocLinksProperty.OnDelete = Microsoft.OData.Edm.EdmOnDeleteAction.None;
            structLocLinksProperty.Name = "LocationLinks";

            var navigationProperty = structType.AddUnidirectionalNavigation(structLocLinksProperty);
            structures.AddNavigationTarget(navigationProperty, locationLinks);

            return edmModel; 
        }
```

The issue I have now is that I have limited ability to access the navigation property in queries.  For example this link works:

```
http://.../OData/Structures(180)/Children?$expand=Locations
```

While this does not.

```
http://.../OData/Structures(180)/Children?$expand=LocationLinks
```

The error returned is

> {   "error":   {
>       "code":"","message":"An error has occurred.","innererror":
>       {
>         "message":"Instance property 'LocationLinks' is not defined for type 'ConnectomeDataModel.Structure'",
>         "type":"System.ArgumentException","stacktrace":"   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression,
>   String propertyName)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.CreatePropertyValueExpressionWithFilter(IEdmEntityType
>   elementType, IEdmProperty property, Expression source, FilterClause
>   filterClause)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.BuildPropertyContainer(IEdmEntityType
>   elementType, Expression source, Dictionary`2 propertiesToExpand,
>   ISet`1 propertiesToInclude, ISet`1 autoSelectedProperties, Boolean
>   isSelectingOpenTypeSegments)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.ProjectElement(Expression
>   source, SelectExpandClause selectExpandClause, IEdmEntityType
>   entityType)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectExpandBinder.Bind(IQueryable
>   queryable)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplySelectExpand[T](T
>   entity, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query,
>   ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response,
>   HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n
>   at 
>   System.Web.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext
>   actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End
>   of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at  System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at 
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at 
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"
>       }   } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xycor

As mentioned from you, `LocationLinks` should be same as `Locations` for `Structure`. So, What you have done for controller and action, I think, is correct. I have a test based on your description and it seems Web API OData can route the `GetLocationLinks` by convention.

Let me show my metadata document, please ignore the namespace and compare it with yours and let me know any difference. Thanks.

```
<Schema Namespace="ODataConsoleSample" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
  <EntityType Name="LocationLink">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="A" />
      <PropertyRef Name="B" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="A" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="B" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="Structure">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="Locations" Type="Collection(ODataConsoleSample.Location)" />
    <NavigationProperty Name="LocationLinks" Type="Collection(ODataConsoleSample.LocationLink)" />
  </EntityType>
  <EntityType Name="Location">
    <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="ParentId" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false" />
  </EntityType>
  <Function Name="StructureLocationLinks" IsBound="true">
    <Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Collection(ODataConsoleSample.Structure)" />
    <Parameter Name="StructureID" Type="Edm.Int64" Nullable="false" />
    <ReturnType Type="ODataConsoleSample.LocationLink" />
  </Function>
  <EntityContainer Name="Container">
    <EntitySet Name="LocationLinks" EntityType="ODataConsoleSample.LocationLink" />
    <EntitySet Name="Structures" EntityType="ODataConsoleSample.Structure">
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="Locations" Target="Locations" />
      <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="LocationLinks" Target="LocationLinks" />
    </EntitySet>
    <EntitySet Name="Locations" EntityType="ODataConsoleSample.Location" />
  </EntityContainer>
</Schema>
```

Comment: That looks reasonable.  However I believe I have to add the Navigation property when configuring the OData service.  The EDMX I have is generated from the database.  This is the function import for the EDMX.  When I set the IsBound="True" property to the function definition I get a property not allowed error.

Comment: Please ignore the comment above.  I posted by accident and by the time I editted it into shape it was locked.  This is the proper response:  That looks reasonable.  However I believe I have to add the NavigationProperty to the ODataConventionBuilder when configuring the OData service.  The EDMX I have is generated from the database.  My function definition is missing the IsBound property.  When I set the IsBound="True" property to the function definition I get a property not allowed error.  There seem to be other issues that I will dig into more tomorrow.  Thanks for taking a look at this.